# How to use GPShell to upload applets on a Java Card

Tags: java, applet, javacard, globalplatform

I want to upload an applet on a javacard and I downloaded the GPShell folder on GitHub.
But since there is no .exe file to execute like with gp.exe, i don't kno how to use it (Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a zip from the [GPShell release](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/releases) page. The latest version is [2.0.0](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/releases/tag/2.0.0)